# Asymptotic Complexity for Lazy evaluation

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In Strict evaluation its easier to reason about the asymptotic complexity of a program because because the sub expressions that will be evaluated and When they will be evaluated is syntactically apparent. Which is not the case with languages of Lazy evaluation. I find it hard to speculate if an expression is `O(n) , O(logn) or O(nlogn)`

What would be the best way to tackle asymptotic complexity with Lazy evaluation ?
 Someone who can explain for me to understand would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

With strict evaluation, cost of calculation = cost of use.

If you do `xs.map(cos)`, you pay cost of `cos` * length(`xs`).

With lazy evaluation, cost of use < cost of calculation. How specifically it is lower, very much depends on the shape of the computation.

One of the simplest forms of lazy evaluation is short-circuiting of Boolean expressions. Look at `(x) => (cheap(x) || expensive(x))`.

Its cost of computation greatly depends on how often `cheap(x)` is true, so that `expensive(x)` is not invoked. Same applies to other lazy computations, e.g. the use of cache / memoization, use of generators, etc.

To my mind, the big-O approach is not reasonably applicable to problems like these, unless you can find a clear dependency between the size of the problem (which big-O is about) and the rate of lazy computation actually being performed.